# How can I signal a thread to stop waiting for a Mutex once it's been joined?

Tags: .net, multithreading, join, wait

I noticed that some of my services were hanging instead of shutting down, as instructed, because they were waiting on locks held by other services that are waiting for them to shut down (causing a deadlock). To that end, I needed some way to signal the threads waiting for the lock to shut down, so I came up with this:

```
public static Boolean Lock(this Mutex mutex)
{
 Boolean achieved = false;

 while (Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.StopRequested)
 {
  try
  {
   achieved = mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0));
  }
  catch (AbandonedMutexException exception)
  {
   // Log this
  }
 }

 return achieved;
}
```

When each service is stopped, it calls Join on each of its threads. The problem is that the even after Thread has been called, the ThreadState is still set to Running. Eventually, the Join will timeout and the thread will be aborted, but I'd rather it not come to that.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there some way for the thread to know that it's been joined (and thus can stop waiting)?
2. Is there a better way to solve this problem than what I've come up with here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a global manual-reset event, set it at service shutdown before joining your threads and use `WaitHandle.WaitAny (mutex, stopEvent)` in your `Lock` function:

```
internal static EventWaitHandle s_stopEvent ;

// in service startup code:
s_stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent (false) ;

public static void Stop (this IEnumerable<Thread> threads)
{
  s_stopEvent.Set () ;
  foreach (var thread in threads)
    thread.Join () ;
}

public static bool Lock (this Mutex mutex)
{
  try
  {
    return WaitHandle.WaitAny (new WaitHandle[] { mutex, s_stopEvent }) == 0 ;
  }
  catch (AbandonedMutexException exception)
  {
    // Log this
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

You have to build cancellation mechanism into the task that your threads are running, so no threading mechanism - apart from cancellation - can help.

Have a look here:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Cancellation_Tokens

Comment: Is the idea that the Cancellation Token replaces my join, and I throw that and catch Cancelation Exception when I want my threads to shut down? That seems a bit like doing an abort in that it disregards state. Is that good practice? Is there a way to do that more gracefully?

Comment: Yes, this is a different approach replacing your join. The work threads are doing will include checking a cancelled flag in which case they will stop and no join will required.